# Unable to run flutter -v or flutter doctor in command prompt on Windows 10

Tags: flutter

I come to this issue whenever I try to run Flutter command on command prompt on Windows 10 Pro.

```
PS C:\src\flutter> flutter doctor
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
/C:/Users/laich/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/build-1.2.1/lib/src/analyzer/resolver.dart:6:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/laich/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.38.5/lib/dart/element/element.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart';
       ^
/C:/Users/laich/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/build-1.2.1/lib/src/builder/build_step.dart:7:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/laich/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.38.5/lib/dart/element/element.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart';
       ^
/C:/Users/laich/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/linter-0.1.101/lib/src/ast.dart:8:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/laich/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.38.5/lib/dart/element/element.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart';
       ^
/C:/Users/laich/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/build-1.2.1/lib/src/builder/build_step_impl.dart:7:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/laich/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.38.5/lib/dart/element/element.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart';
       ^
/C:/Users/laich/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.38.5/lib/src/lint/linter.dart:11:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/laich/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.38.5/lib/dart/element/element.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart';
       ^
Error: Unable to create dart snapshot for flutter tool.
```

Looking like it gets stuck at

> running pub upgrade

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Reminder: we're after readable technical writing here. In particular, when referring to yourself ("I") it is always a capital letter. Running an English spellchecker prior to posting can catch most of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the flutter install directory and run the following commands

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```

And your problem should be fixed.

**Note:**

For those on windows, if you use `git bash` you'll have a problem like:
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine fee001c93f25a1e7258e762781a7361f122d29f5...
Unknown operating system. Cannot install Dart SDK.

Use windows terminal directly.

Comment: After the above command, it shown Unknown operating system. Cannot install Dart SDK. when running flutter doctor

Comment: Are you using git bash?

Comment: Yes, it's on git bash

Comment: use command prompt. (cmd). Navigate to the installation directory then hold down shift and right-click to see `open command here`. then run the commands

Comment: Got this error  Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/laich/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.38.5/lib/dart/element/element.dart': The system cannot find the path specified. when running pub upgrade in flutter doctor